# Wireguard APP on iOS and split tunneling

Tags: ios, vpn

Can the [Wireguard App](https://apps.apple.com/it/app/wireguard/id1441195209) for iOS be used for split tunneling? I have just inserted just one IP 192.168.1.100/32 in Allowed IPs. I can reach it but then I can't surf the internet anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the DNS was not into Allowed IPs. Thanks to the Wireguard support chat!